# How to call a .bat file from any location in CMD on Windows

Tags: windows, command, prompt

I have a Batch file which I want to execute in CMD from any directory. Something like this:

File name: MyBatch

Path: C:\MyBatch.bat

Open CMD:
c:\Program Files> MyBatch

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 9):

Set that location in your PATH environmental variable.

I wouldn't put it the root or the system directory.

I keep a directory with all my scripts in C:\DRR\CMD

and either set it in the MyComputer GUI or run at the command script:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\DRR\CMD
```

Comment: Thank you this worked for me. I ended up putting all my batch files in `C:\aliases` and I can call `psql` cd to commonly used directories, run tasks and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You could just put it in your `c:\windows\system32` directory, as its always in the system path.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a legitimate way to accomplish the task

Comment: Bad idea, and unless user is in Admin group, the batch file can't be put there, anyhow.

Comment: Never put user stuff into c:\Windows\System32 (regular user cannot write into that directory anyway - and for a good reason)

Comment: Yeah but the question is "irrespective of what PATH is set to" all the other solutions suggest adding or modifying the path.

Answer (score 1):

How about...
`"%MyBatch%"`? (the double qoutes are intended)

That should work!

to change your Variable, use `set MyBatch="Path\Whatever.bat"`

and to ask the user for a String, use `set /p MyBatch="Question? "`
-- or, you can use a BAT-to-EXE converter to run the batch in a Executable.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set the PATH environment variable to include the path to your batch file

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking Windows, then the PATH Environment variable is what you need to set.

The path where your bat file is placed should be appended to the PATH variable. 
In your example append "C:\;" in the value for Path environment variable.

Then you can execute MyBatch.bat from anywhere on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder called `Batches` (lets say in your C drive).

Append C:\Batches in your `path` environment variable and you then can run batch files in that directory from anywhere.